# How to convert raw query MYSQL to Laravel framework

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8

I don't know how i can use this code below in Laravel 5.8
I already tried but i doesn't work correctly.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT *, SUM(amount) AS SumBudget FROM messages GROUP BY contact_phone ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC LIMIT 3");

$orderList = 0;
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $orderList++;
    $user = $data['user']; 
    $cost = $data['SumBudget'];
    if ($orderList == 1) {
        printf("%d. %s %d‎฿<br>", $orderList, $user, $cost);
    }
    else if ($orderList == 2)
    {
        printf("%d. %s %d‎฿<br>", $orderList, $user, $cost);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("%d. %s %d‎฿<br>", $orderList, $user, $cost);
    }
}
```

My code already tried.

```
$data = DB::table('messages')
        ->where('phone_number', $request->phone_number)
        ->select(DB::raw('SUM(amount) as cost'))
        ->groupBy(DB::raw('contact_phone'))
        ->orderBy(DB::raw('SUM(amount)', 'DESC'))
        ->limit(3)
        ->get();
```

Can anyone help me, Thank you.

Comment: Hint: You also can use a RAW query in Laraval without using the Query builder.

Comment: Yep, i use DB:: then put my code after DB:: and laravel give me error Syntax error or access violation: 1055

Comment: I think we talk past one and other.. i meant `DB::connection()->getPdo()->query(...)` should be fine you don't have user input in your qeury.. Atleast not in the example at the top..

Comment: ... which makes me wonder why is there a WHERE in the laravel PHP code it wasn't in the native PHP/MySQL code..

Comment: .. also `SELECT * GROUP BY contact_phone` is generally not how you should be writing SQL.. [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could help you:

```php
DB::table('messages')
    ->select('column_name', /* ... */, DB::raw('SUM(amount) AS cost'))
    ->where('phone_number', $request->phone_number) // if you want to filter
    ->groupBy('contact_phone')
    ->orderBy('cost', 'DESC')
    ->take(3)
    ->get()
```

Comment: `SELECT * GROUP BY contact_phone` is generally not how you should be writing SQL.. [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) .. Running this query can mean invalid results..

Comment: @RaymondNijland You're absolutely right one more time. I updated my example :)

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'laravel.messages.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `id`, SUM(amount) AS cost from `messages` where `phone_number` = 0973279939 group by `contact_phone` order by `cost` desc limit 3)

Comment: I adjust select column_name to select id then i got an error Syntax error or access violation: 1055

Comment: Yes because `id` column isn't in group by clause. Mysql doesn't know how to group all these differents IDs. Because you don't seems to need this ID in your loop so I wouldn't take it in your Mysql query. You should select only `user` column (I suppose for one phone number, you always have the same user) and `SUM(amount) AS cost`